# How to enable sadc cron jobs?

Tags: sysstat

I've installed sysstat and no log are generated in /var/log/sysstat

when I do `sudo /etc/init.d/sysstat status`

I get

```
 * sadc cron jobs are disabled
```

how do I enable sadc cron jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set `ENABLED="true"` in `/etc/default/sysstat` (it is `false` by default on installation in Ubuntu and maybe other distros)?

Then you should be able to start it with `sudo service sysstat restart`